# Delete rows from csv file that don't start with specific keyword?

Tags: python

I have test.csv file  like below

```
aa123,abc
ab123,bcd
si_a23,bcd
da123,abc
si_b24,bcd
```

And here I need to delete all the rows that doesn't start with si_ so my final output file should be

```
si_a23,bcd
si_b24,bcd
```

So far I did this in code -

```
    f = open("test.csv","r")
   lines = f.readlines()
   f.close()
   f = open("test.csv","w")
   for line in lines:
   if line.startswith ("si_"):
       f.write(line)
   f.close()
```

I get a output with blank file. What I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Read the rows, check the first column, write out matching lines. Which part are you having trouble with? Show your code so far and someone can help you fix it. This is how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following code (posted by you) and it works just fine with your example.

```
f = open("test.csv","r")
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

f = open("test.csv","w")
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith ("si_"):
        f.write(line)
f.close()
```

But may I suggest you use some debugging code, e.g.:

- print(lines)
- print(line)

And maybe also write to a new file while you are trying (to not overwrite).

Comment: You are right, actually it was my mistake. in the test data which I was using has si- instead of si_ due to which all records where removed. Thanks for confirming though.